# Trying to install pip but installation defaults to python 2.7 instead of 3.6

Tags: python, macos

I'm learning Python and trying to install pip by typing

```
python get-pip.py
```

in the same directory as the get-pip.py file.  But it seems to try to install pip to the version of Python that came with my OSX as opposed to my new Python installation (3.6).   Do I need to add a path to the command above to force it to install pip to my Python 3.6?

I'm new to this, so my apologies if this is a dumb question :-)

Comment: `which python` will show you the exact path of your current python executable. Use exact path of python2.7 to install pip to it. Or `python2.7 get-pip.py` might work.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `python3` or do `alias python=python3` do default to python3